# monaco-editor emulate cursor keys

Tags: monaco-editor

I'd like to emulate cursor movement and indent/outdent using standard HTML buttons in a web browser because most tablet on-screen keyboards do not include arrow keys. I have found that I can trigger ident/outdent using:

```
editor.trigger('anyString', 'editor.action.indentLines', null)

editor.trigger('anyString', 'editor.action.outdentLines', null)
```

How can I emulate arrow key cursor motions? I have not been able to find the correct trigger commands.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `editor.getPosition()` and `editor.setPosition()`

```
// Move right
pos = editor.getPosition()
pos.column = pos.column + 1
window.editor.setPosition(pos)

// Move left
pos = editor.getPosition()
pos.column = pos.column - 1
window.editor.setPosition(pos)

// Move up
pos = editor.getPosition()
pos.lineNumber = pos.lineNumber - 1
window.editor.setPosition(pos)

// Move down
pos = editor.getPosition()
pos.lineNumber = pos.lineNumber + 1
window.editor.setPosition(pos)
```